# Condition for linear minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I'm just wondering that there is a necessary and sufficient condition for [minimal polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) for in which cases are them linear.

Let $A$ be a square matrix. I think that $A$ has a linear minimal polynomial if and only if $A=cI$ for some $c$ constant. Furthermore, the minimal polynomial is $x-c$.

Is that true?

In that special case, if $c=0$, then $A$ is zero matrix and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$ is a polynomial $f \ne 0$ such that: $f(A) = 0$, $f$ is monic and $f$ has minimal degree with these conditions.

Now suppose $A$ has a linear minimal polynomial $f$. Then, since $f$ is monic (by definition), $f$ has the form $f(x) = x - c$ for some constant $c$. We also have $f(A) = 0$, that is, $A - cI = 0$, hence $A = cI$. Conversely, if $A = cI$ than it has a linear minimal polynomial (do the same reasoning backwards).

So yes, it is true.